The involutive structure on a division ring
This question is motivated by foundations of geometry, namely, by studying scalars in affine spaces.
Let $F$ be a field (or better a division ring). It has the operations of addition and multiplication, $+$ and $\cdot$. The operation of addition induces the involution $i:F\to F$, $i:x\mapsto 1-x$, exchanging zero and unit in $F$.
Remark. The operations of multiplication and involution uniquely determine the operation of addition because
$$x-y=x\cdot(1-x^{-1}y)=x\cdot i(x^{-1}y)$$for every $x,y\in F$ with $x\ne 0$. Then $-y$ is the unique element of $F$ such that $-y\ne x\cdot i(x^{-1}y)$ for every $x\ne 0$. Then $x+y=x-(-y)=x\cdot i(x^{-1}(-y))$, so the addition is uniquely determined by multiplication and inversion.
I am interested in studying the algebraic structure $(F,\cdot,i)$ consisting of a set $F$, a binary operation $\cdot$ turning $F$ into a group with attached zero, and an involution $i:F\to F$ such that $i(0)=1$.
Question 1. Which axioms should be imposed on the algebraic structure $(F,\cdot,i)$ to guarantee that $\cdot$ and $i$ are the multiplication and involution of some field structure on $F$?
Remark. One of possible answers is to determine the partial operation $x-y=x\cdot i(x^{-1}y)$ for $x,y\in F$ with $x\ne 0$, then add an axiom saying that for every $y$ there exists a unique element $-y$ such that $-y\ne x\cdot i(x^{-1}y)$ for all $x\ne 0$, then define the operation of addition letting $x+y=x\cdot i(x^{-1}\cdot(-y))$, and then write down all axioms of a field in terms of operations $\cdot$ and $i$. But this will be long and artificial. Are there more natural choices to axiomatizing the structure $(F,\cdot,i)$?
Question 2. Has the algebraic structure $(F,\cdot,i)$ some standard name (like involutive monoid with zero)?

Rather than defining $-y$ by a non-equality as you do, it might be easier to define it using the equality $-y := i(y) - 1 = i(y).i(i(y)^{-1})$ (unless $y=1$).

@TomDeMedts Thank you for this nice suggestion to define $-y$ as $i(y)\cdot i(i(y)^{-1})$ for $y\ne 1$. So, only the element $-1$ remains somewhat mysterious (from the viewpoint of multiplication and involution).

"circle composition" (see for example here) has always seemed close to me, but it seems the transported structure from $F$ to $F$ under the involution operation is $x\circ y = x+y - xy$ rather than $x+y+xy$.  Maybe the spirit of your question is different because you're probably not that interested in this transport.

@rschwieb Thank you for your suggestion. Indeed, the operation transported from the multiplication by the map $1-x$ is $x+y-xy=1-(1-x)(1-y)$. My motivation is geometric: for scalars (which are equivalence classes of triples of collinear points) it is easy to define the operation of multiplication $abc\cdot acd:=abd$ and the operation of involution: $1-xyz:=zyx$. But to define the operation of addition of scalars one should involve more complicated machinery (of vectors). So, for scalars, those two operations (multiplication and involution) are natural and the addition is a derived operation.

@rschwieb Because of that I asked about possible more general algebraic context of this situation.
